# Unable to change WHOID of Event with Shared Activities are enabled

Tags: event, shared-activities

I'm getting the below error, whenever i'm trying to update the WHOID of the Event.

> Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00U3600000MA8x4EAD;
>   first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, The update to shared
>   activity 00U3600000MA8x4 failed because of a conflict between the
>   primary WhoId and the WhoIds in EventWhoIds.: [WhoId]

The EventRelation record for the value that i want to update in WHOID is already present with IsParent as true and IsInvitee as false.

Whenver I'm updating the events WHOID from Workbench it's working fine. But from VFRemoting or future callout, i'm getting above error.

Is there any way to update WHOID of evnt when shared activities are enabled?

Comment: Do you have a trigger updating the whoid?

Comment: No, I don't have any trigger on Event object

Comment: @HemantKeni did you find a solution?  We are running into the same issue.